# Block/allow specific subprocesses being launched by a process

Tags: sudo, selinux, process-management, apparmor

I block all Internet traffic for my kids' Linux accounts using iptables. Sometimes I want to allow them to use one program or another. In such cases I enable them to run that program as another(unlimited) user via sudoers. This time I tried to enable them to use zoom [as described here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/609631/44880) and it worked. The problem is that zoom launches browser (e.g. once clicked on "Help") as the unlimited user which makes the whole approach totally useless.

Is there a way to limit the user `kiddy` to be able to run only `sudo -u daddy /usr/bin/zoom` and at the same time block zoom from launching browser (or maybe even any subprocesses)?

Comment: You can do it with app-armour. Config is a little involved, but there may be a config for this already written. The hard bit is getting it to stop everything that you want to stop, while not stopping it from working.

Comment: I'd suggest to update the summary, because you do not want to prevent subprocesses in general, but either disallow specific ones or just allow specific ones (it seems to me)

Answer (score 3):

You can prevent a process from forking children by setting the `RLIMIT_NPROC` limit. For instance, with `zsh`:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
limit -h maxproc 0
exec zoom "$@"
```

Would start `zoom` and prevent it from forking children by setting a *hard* limit on the maximum number of processes.

Now, I can't tell about `zoom` specifically, but depending on the application, that may prevent it from working as it may fork children as part of its normal operation. Also note that it would still be able to execute `firefox` in the same process. Forking processes and executing commands are two different things. That's how the process running `zsh` is able to execute `zoom` in that script.