# sudo: get sound playback running as another user

Tags: linux, sudo, gnome

I block all Internet traffic for my kids' Linux accounts using iptables. Sometimes I want to allow them to use one program or another. In such cases I enable them to run that programs as another(unlimited) user via sudoers. This time I tried to enable them to use [translate-shell](https://github.com/soimort/translate-shell) and `mpg123` for playing sounds/pronouncing translated words:

`kiddy   ALL= (daddy) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/trans`

However running `sudo -u daddy trans en:he -speak -player mpg123 apple` as `kiddy` user shows correct translation in the terminal but doesn't play the sound, stating: "Voice output isn't available for English". Once I log in as `daddy` in Gnome and run the same command: `trans en:he -speak -player mpg123 apple` - everything works as expected and I get both the textual translation and the sound playback. Both users belong to the `audio` group. I tried [this approach](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/608677/sudo-run-zoom-as-another-user) but id didn't help. I am on Debian 12 and neither on Wayland nor on Xorg there is no file `$HOME/.Xauthority` which was used for that solution...

How can I cause the translate-shell to playback audio via sudo as another user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Göran Uddeborg's answer I did this:

1. chmod 705 $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
2. using `sudo visudo` I added these lines:

```
Defaults:kiddy env_keep += "XDG_RUNTIME_DIR"
kiddy   ALL= (daddy) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/trans
```

Now it works!

Answer (score 1):

Audio devices on modern system are managed by *pipewire* which has a socket in your `/run/user` directory. In order for the sudo:ed process to access the current session's pipewire instance, you would need to allow it access to the socket `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/pipewire-0`. The socket itself is normally open to anyone, but `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` is not.

A command sequence that would work would be

```
chmod a+x $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
sudo -u daddy  XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR trans en:he -speak -player mpg123 apple
```

Do consider, however, that you are opening `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` to anyone here which you might not want.

Comment: thank you! Is adding write permissions `w` indeed needed?

Comment: `chmod 705 $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` seems to be enough, but setting $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR inside sudo cause it to complain and exit.

Comment: Good point, others don't need `w`, nor `r` for that matter. I updated the suggestion for any future visitors. If the group or others need the extra `x` bit depends on if `kiddy` and `daddy` share any group or not. You could have had a _family_ group! :-)